# ACL for fair-scheduler in YARN is not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have configured my queue with ACL in fair-scheduler.xml.
    But other users are also able to run job into the same queue.
    Do i need to  define ACL somwhere else, as per my queue.
    Any link or help would be appreciated.Thanks

```
 <queue name="queue1">
            <minResources>10000mb,10vcores</minResources>
            <maxResources>30000mb,30vcores</maxResources>
            <maxRunningApps>10</maxRunningApps>
            <weight>2.0</weight>
            <schedulingMode>fair</schedulingMode>
            <aclAdministerApps>User1</aclAdministerApps>
            <aclSubmitApps>User1</aclSubmitApps>
    </queue>
```

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html

Comment: I followed that guide. My question is, do i need to define ACL rules anywhere else beside fair-scheduler.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<queue name="root">
<aclSubmitApps> </aclSubmitApps>
<queue name="queue1">
        <minResources>10000mb,10vcores</minResources>
        <maxResources>30000mb,30vcores</maxResources>
        <maxRunningApps>10</maxRunningApps>
        <weight>2.0</weight>
        <schedulingMode>fair</schedulingMode>
        <aclAdministerApps>User1</aclAdministerApps>
        <aclSubmitApps>User1</aclSubmitApps>
</queue> 
</queue>
```

It is working for me .Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

NB: this is about the *capacity* scheduler. Not sure if the Fair scheduler ACL inheritance behavior is different.

ACLs are configured via `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.acl_submit_applications`, see [Capacity Scheduler](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html):

> `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.<queue-path>.acl_submit_applications`   The ACL which controls who can submit applications to the given queue. If the given user/group has necessary ACLs on the given queue or one of the parent queues in the hierarchy they can submit applications. ACLs for this property are inherited from the parent queue if not specified.

Note the bit about queues inheriting the parent queue ACLs. Since usually all queues inherit from root queue and the root queue ACL is left in default [capacity-scheduler.xml](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/conf/capacity-scheduler.xml) as `*`:

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications</name>
 <value>*</value>
 <description>
  The ACL of who can submit jobs to the default queue.
 </description>
</property>
```

it follows that normally all queues get ACLs for all users (`*`) to be able to submit. When you configure queues you should make sure you restrict parent queues as well as your desired queue.

### Update

After looking at the FS queue code I must conclude that the behavior is the same. The access check is done in [`AllocationConfiguration.hasAccess()`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/AllocationConfiguration.java):

```
 public boolean hasAccess(String queueName, QueueACL acl,
      UserGroupInformation user) {
    int lastPeriodIndex = queueName.length();
    while (lastPeriodIndex != -1) {
      String queue = queueName.substring(0, lastPeriodIndex);
      if (getQueueAcl(queue, acl).isUserAllowed(user)) {
        return true;
      }

      lastPeriodIndex = queueName.lastIndexOf('.', lastPeriodIndex - 1);
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Not that the code iterates over the queue hierarchy (by splitting ad each period in the name) until one of the parent queues grants access. Exactly  like the capacity scheduler behavior. Until it reaches the root queue, at which moment this little snippet of code takes effect:

```
/**
   * Get the ACLs associated with this queue. If a given ACL is not explicitly
   * configured, include the default value for that ACL.  The default for the
   * root queue is everybody ("*") and the default for all other queues is
   * nobody ("")
   */
  public AccessControlList getQueueAcl(String queue, QueueACL operation) {
    Map<QueueACL, AccessControlList> queueAcls = this.queueAcls.get(queue);
    if (queueAcls != null) {
      AccessControlList operationAcl = queueAcls.get(operation);
      if (operationAcl != null) {
        return operationAcl;
      }
    }
    return (queue.equals("root")) ? EVERYBODY_ACL : NOBODY_ACL;
  }
```

Also note how queues are loaded, from [`AllocationFileLoaderService.reloadAllocations()`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/AllocationFileLoaderService.java):

```
// Load queue elements.  A root queue can either be included or omitted.  If
// it's included, all other queues must be inside it.
for (Element element : queueElements) {
  String parent = "root";
  ...
  loadQueue(parent, element, minQueueResources, maxQueueResources,
      queueMaxApps, userMaxApps, queueMaxAMShares, queueWeights,
      queuePolicies, minSharePreemptionTimeouts, queueAcls,
      configuredQueues);
}

/**
* Loads a queue from a queue element in the configuration file
*/
private void loadQueue(String parentName, Element element, ...) 
  throws AllocationConfigurationException {
String queueName = element.getAttribute("name");
if (parentName != null) {
  queueName = parentName + "." + queueName;
}
```

Notice how queue names are actually concatenated with parent queue and `"root"` is the implicit parent of all queues. Therefore your queue name is truly `root.queue1`.

So what that means is that in the FS scheduler all queues by default give access to everybody because they all inherit the `root` queue default access. You need to explicitly override the `root` queue ACLs in your config file. This is no different from the CapacityScheduler, but I think that the CS behavior of getting the default form config is superior to the FS behavior of getting the default from code.

I did not actually tested the FS behavior, but the code probably executes as it reads.

Comment: Yeah Capacity Scheduler have that option, was trying get my hands dirty on fair-scheduler.As per their documentation
    http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html

We can use aclSubmitApps to control user per queue.Unfortunately that functionality is not working .Not sure if i am missing something in my config.

Comment: You are correct, every queue is getting inherited from root. (e.g, root.queue1). And by default root has all permission.I tried setting permission in mapred-queue-acls.xml .
     mapred.queue.root.acl-submit-job as " ".
Is this the correct file & permission.

Comment: I don't know how to configure root, but I would expect something like `<queue name="root"><aclSubmitApps></aclSubmitApps></queue>` in the `fair-scheduler.xml`.

Comment: Afaik `mapred-queue-acls.xml` is for legacy mapred, not applicable to YARN.

Answer (score 1):

Write “root” queue in the file，which is the value  of yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file.

ex:

In the yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file</name>
  <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/fair-scheduler.xml</value>
</property>
```

In the fair-scheduler.xml,should define the acl right for root queue.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <allocations>
 <queue name="root">
 <aclSubmitApps>user1,user2</aclSubmitApps>
 <aclAdministerApps>user1,user2,user3</aclAdministerApps>
 <minResources>xxxx mb,xxxvcores</minResources>
 <maxResources>xxxx mb,xxxvcores</maxResources>
 <maxRunningApps>30</maxRunningApps>
 <minSharePreemptionTimeout>10</minSharePreemptionTimeout>

 <!--sub queue begin-->
 <queue name="mapreduce">
 <minResources>xxxx mb,xxvcores</minResources>
 <maxResources>xxxx mb,xxvcores</maxResources>
```

...

```
 </queue>
</allocations>
```

**If users are authorized for parent queue,they are authorized for son queue.
Root queue's default acl policy is "*",so,all users are authorized for all queues.**

Comment: <aclSubmitApps>user1,user2</aclSubmitApps> is working

 <aclAdministerApps>user1,user2,user3</aclAdministerApps> is not working .Is it working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `allocations.xml` in `/etc/hadoop/` folder.
Define all those properties in `allocations.xml`

Also specify scheduler related changes in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.allocation.file</name>
  <value>allocations.xml</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I have added these files,it is picking up the queue.Only functionality that is not working is aclSubmitApp. Is there any other file, where we define UserAcl.Thanks

Comment: No,this is only file where we do all the configuration related to fair scheduling .